# BackgroundWorker getting stuck

Tags: c#, list, backgroundworker

I have a serial port reading lines of string from a device.
I created a class called Node that stores the three pieces of information from the string in their own variables.

Node.cs

```
class Node
{
    public Int32 Count;
    public Int32 ID;
    public Int32 Length;
    public String Data;

    public Node(Int32 ID, String Data, Int32 Length)
    {
        Count = 1;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Data = Data;
        this.Length = Length;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return ID.ToString() + " [" + Data + "] " + Length.ToString();
    }
    public static Boolean Equals(Node cmp, Node cmp2)
    {
        return (cmp.ID == cmp2.ID && cmp.Data == cmp2.Data);
    }
}
```

The backgroundworker is located in another class called SerialThread.cs
The serial port reads a line of data from the device and creates a Node object and stores that node in a List.

```
    private void thread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (serial.IsOpen)
        {
            GUI.UpdateStatusLabelText("Connected to " + portName);
        }

        while (serial.IsOpen)
        {
            String buffer = serial.ReadLine();
            String[] parsed;
            if (buffer.Length > 10)
            {
                GUI.UpdateStatusLabelText("stuck");
                parsed = buffer.Split('+');
                Node parseNode = new Node(Int32.Parse(parsed[0]), parsed[1], Int32.Parse(parsed[2]));
                list.AddToList(parseNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

The thread will cycle one time and successfully add a node object to the list.  However it will no longer cycle after the first (one time it added two, but never got any larger than that).

After some trial and error, I created a Node in the global variables that remains the same, then commented out the "Node parseNode = new ..." line and kept adding that global node to the list, then the list continued to grow.

So it would appear that upon recreating the parseNode object the thread will just freeze.

Comment: When you debug and step through with a debugger line by line what happens? Also if you enable "[Break when exception is thrown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx)" are any exceptions getting thrown?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: No exceptions are thrown.  The list size remains at 1.  I also have ruled out the serial device causing the issue because I added a method to save 'buffer' to a file and it grew.  The creation of new Node is the culprit.

Comment: That `GUI.UpdateStatusLabelText` looks suspicious; you should not be doing anything on the GUI thread in a BackgroundWorker. If you need to update a GUI thread you should be calling `ReportProgress`, which I don't see anywhere in your code.

Comment: You still did not answer my first question, when you use a debugger and put a breakpoint inside your function and step line by line, what happens? The only thing that can "Go wrong" with the creation of `Node` is the `Int32.Parse` throws a exception, but you just told us that you are getting no exceptions.

Comment: That calls a delegate void on the MainForm that updates a status label.

Comment: Why don't you comment out your `GUI.UpdateStatusLabelText` code (You shouldn't be touching UI from any other thread except UI thread itself), put `dummy` int values while creating `Node` instance and try adding to the list. See what happens.

Comment: Are you sure that all lines are passed through `buffer.Length > 10`